# Filter objects by matching it with another list by its nested list elements with a condition

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I am trying to filter and collect objects with a condition using Java8 streams

I have a list of Instance which has a nested list of Element

```
public class Model {
List<Instance> instances;
}
public class Instance {
private String name;
List<Element> elements;
}
public class Element {
private String partNumber;
}
```

Below is example josn

```
{
    "instances": [
        {
            "name": "instance1",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber1"
                },
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "instance2",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber3"
                },
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber4"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And other response object

```
public class Response {
private List<Domain> domains;
}
public class Domain {
private String name;
private List<Hardware> hardwares;
}
public class Hardware {
private String partNumber;
}
```

sample json

```
{
    "domains": [
        {
            "name": "domain1",
            "hardwares": [
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber1"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "domain2",
            "hardwares": [
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber2"
                },
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber3"
                },
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber4"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "domain3",
            "hardwares": [
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber5"
                },
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber6"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I am trying to stream and collect response objects by comparing if the `Hardwares` from domain atleast contain one `partnumber` from request's each element. That means atleast one `hardware` from each `Instance` shuold be present in `Domains` `hardwares` to be consider `Domain` as a valid one.

For the above sample data,

1. domain1 is not a valid domain because it only contains atleast
   one `partnumber` `partNumber1` from `instance1` but does not contain
   atleast one `partnumber` from `instance2`
2. domain2 is a valid
   domain because it contains atleast one `partnumber` `partNumber2`
   from `instance1` and contains atleast one `partnumber` `partNumber3`
   from `instance2`. It can contain additional partnumbers and that is
   ok
3. domain3 is not a valid domain because it does not contains
   atleast one `partnumber` from `instance1` and does not contain
   atleast one `partnumber` from `instance2`

I started writing

```
request.getInstances().stream().flatMap(instance -> instance.getElement().stream().filter(element -> response.getDomains().stream().flatMap(domain -> domain.getHardwares.stream().anyMatch(hardware-> element.contains()
```

but I am having struggle completing this as I have limited understanding of streams

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could probably do it all in one stream, but instead i'd suggest using two streams. First, generate a list of sets of part names from the model; then, stream over the response to find domains such that for each instance, there is some part name from that domain contained in the set of part names of that instance.

```
List<Set<String>> parts = model.getInstances().stream()
        .map(i -> i.getElements().stream()
                .map(Element::getPartNumber)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());

response.getDomains().stream()
        .filter(d -> parts.stream()
                .allMatch(p -> d.getHardwares().stream()
                        .map(Hardware::getPartNumber)
                        .anyMatch(p::contains)))
        .forEach(System.out::println);
```

About your comments: Right now, this should remove all Domains if there is an Instance with no Elements, as the `allMatch` would then fail for that Instance. If instead Instances with no elements should just be ignored, you could add another `filter` to the first stream for creating the `parts` list (not tested):

```
        .filter(i -> ! i.getElements().isEmpty())
```

or maybe `i.getElements() != null`, depending on how it's initialized.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Appreciate your help. This is working for almost all scenarios expect when any of Instance does not have any partnumbers. I tried to limit collecting partnumber only if the list size is greater than 0 by putting a condition here `map(i -> i.getElements().stream()
                .map(Element::getPartNumber)
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()))` but it didn't work. Also I tried to collect the `Domains` by using Collect(Collectors.toList()) by removing the foreach, it is showing compilation error

Comment: No when one instance does not have any hardwares `{
    "instances": [
        {
            "name": "instance1",
            "elements": [
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber1"
                },
                {
                    "partNumber": "partNumber2"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "instance2"
        }
    ]
}`

Comment: This is how my Instance class looks like `public class Instance {
private String name;
List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();
}` as I have initialized list here, it was showing it has two list of sets for partnumbers for Instance2 with second list size as 0

Comment: It worked after remove the initialization and did a null check before processing in the stream. Thanks @tobias_k

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood. You say id does not work in this case. So how should it behave? Should it then fail for all domains, because no domains have hardware from that (empty) instance? Of should that empty instance be ignored? See my edit. Does it work like that?